# Create Folder on SharePoint using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, mkdir

I'm trying to create a folder on SharePoint.

I have code for Excel, that checks if a folder exists. If it doesn't, the code creates it.

I tried to use the `MkDir` function, but apparently it can't be used with SharePoint.

My URL looks something like this: https://XXXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/XXXX/Documents%20partages/XXXX/FA

During my research, some people were talking about mapping, but I have no idea what it means.

Is there a way to create a folder using something similar to MkDir?

Comment: `MkDir` will make folders on the file system of the operating system (e.g. Windows), which are not the same as Sharepoint folders. Sharepoint is a web-based application that has its own methods. This might help https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/creating-new-folder-in-sharepoint-directory-using-vba-excel.1179110/

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins Thanks for your answer. I looked at the different links you sent me, but the problem is that, since other coworkers are supposed to use this program, sync directly to the pc doesn't seem to be a great idea, so i'm not sure if there is something similar to MkDir but compatible with SharePoint

Comment: Have a look at the answer posted by RickJ in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497462/creating-a-new-folder-in-sharepoint-using-vba - this is the method I use and it works well. The only caveat is that a connection **must** be made first manually using [Open in Explorer] - RickJ mentions this in their answer and I've not found a way to automate this. If I don't restart my machine, that connection usually remains for around a week.

Comment: Mapping probably means that you map your sharepoint folder to your local drive, and then every change you do to your local folder is reflected by the sharepoint folder. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/map-a-network-drive-to-a-sharepoint-library-751148de-f579-42f9-bc8c-fcd80ccf0f53